# Should we split questions that contain their own solutions into separate question-and-answer posts?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

Sometimes, new users will ask a question, and in the course of exploring it on their own, or in response to comments, they will figure out what the problem was and include the solution in the question post, effectively rendering it unanswerable (because it has already been solved). [Here is one such example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533585/solved-pygame-projects-wont-run-pygame-error-no-available-video-device)

When we encounter these, is it useful and correct to revise or roll-back the question to an answerable form and move the solution-content to a new answer post? My intuition tells me that this is [very] bad idea, since the process of dividing into two parts another person's already-edited post, with its own internal consistency and inherently-entangled content, will almost certainly be messier than the original and potentially compromise the fidelity of the original. But solved-questions don't match the question-and-answer-posts format SO runs by, *And That Would Be Wrong.*

The most problematic question-edits are ones where the author revises their broken code in a way that solves the problem, making it impossible to tell what the original point of the post was without looking at the edit history of the question itself. Even though this kind of revision is counterproductive, correcting it requires an editor to perform a code edit, which is itself a highly questionable activity.

**In short, my question to Meta is this:** If we find a question-post that has been edited to answer itself, should we (perhaps grudgingly) leave it be, or split it into a question and answer, even if the overall quality of the original post is compromised<sup>**</sup>? To what extent is the question-and-answer format preferable to self-answering-question format? Is there a policy on this?

** (assuming, in all cases, that the resulting posts are both still of normally acceptable quality)

Comment: If question does not look useful closing as "unclear what you asking" may be appropriate (also somewhat not so nice).

Comment: I don't get the point of this question.  The Q+A format is well established and dead-easy to understand.  When somebody mistakes SO for a personal blogging site then they came to the wrong site.  We already have millions of them that get it right, a frecked-up one like that doesn't make the site better and doesn't need anybody's free time.  Unless they care.  You do have to care.  You already know what to do when you care, you don't need our help.

Comment: @HansPassant The point of the question is what we should do when we encounter someone, either through innocent ignorance or abject laziness, makes this mistake. Do we ignore the problem or try and solve it, even though the solution is difficult? I'm not asking if it's okay and I know it's not-- that's why I'm asking at all. I'm asking about what to do when we see it from others. Because I care. But, in this case, it seems apparent to me that, to correct the problem, I would have to tread into some very grey areas.

Comment: @HansPassant Perhaps I've been misunderstood: Do I fix it knowing that the solution could create serious but ambiguous problems, or do I leave an obvious but unremarkable problem alone?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That's a good way of looking at it.

Comment: Purely coincidental: related (but not exactly the same), my [proposal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309266/2564301) to disallow at least title edits. See the bottom there for a few other posts on this issue.

Comment: The answer is "yes"; questions are questions and answers are answers.  If the question is off-topic, vote to close it as such, but you *still* want to separate the question from the answer.