# Actively prevent [NOT SOLVED YET] in title

Tags: feature-request, title, quality-filter

I was surprised to find someone commenting on a self-answer that "the proper etiquette is to add 'Solved' to your title and edit it into your question". I commented rather brusque (firmly yet polite – or so I tell myself), and fortunately the commenter was on-line and so we briefly discussed this, ending in a *mea culpa* from him and a confession it was the Proper Thing To Do on other fora where he hangs out.

My sort of stock comment to [edits like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33455151/7) which add "Solved", "Fixed", "Answered" or something similar, is

> It is not necessary to edit your post and add "Solved", as it would invalidate the purpose of Stack Overflow as a question and answer site (it would no longer be a question). If you feel this question warrants a proper answer, you can post one.

and someone else's comment, equally useful:

> If your problem was solved by somebody's answer, please mark that answer as correct. If you came up with this answer yourself, please write it up as an answer in the answers section (not as part of the question) and mark it correct.

The list of "Solved" question titles [`title:solved`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Asolved) lists just over 3,000. So it appears that such edits are indeed actively rolled back.

Is it possible to **take preemptive action** when someone edits a title and tries to add "solved" or "fixed", similar to mentioning you have a "problem" in a title?

[image: I have a problem :P]

.. something like this perhaps?

[image: it's Stacky!]

---

Separate from taking preemptive action:

In order to justify removing the phrase from a title (and possibly from the question body as well): should we supply a **canonical FAQ** question-and-answer to state that (1) SO is a question-and-answer site (as two separate entities), and (2) there is a clear indicator that a question has an accepted answer?

---

Alas, [`is:q body:solved`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+body%3Asolved) lists way, way more: 65,281, including horrible ones such as these two:

[image: SOLVED SOLVED SOLVED YIPPEEE]

and

[image: problem solved, So Many Times]

(both have been rolled back now to a more sensible state).

Heavy handed edits such as the above can be spotted easily in the search list and even on the front page, but as we all know our lovely community can be surprisingly creative when it comes to "circumventing the rules". So it may not be possible to be able to catch post-edits as easily as title additions.

---

(Discussed-but-not-answered earlier in [Suggest to post answer / accept one when changing title to "Solved"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294924/2564301), and answered in [Automatically remove '[solved]' from questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262123/automatically-remove-solved-from-questions) – neither propose an automatic warning, though. A Meta-meta solution: [edit one at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172501/community-edit-request-solved-fixed-answered).)

Comment: Yep, I rolled those two back...

Comment: Good idea, that's one repetitive wrong question edit appearing all the time.

Comment: @Deduplicator: so that leaves some 65,379 yet to go, eh? ;) If you clicked my Search link: those two sticked out like sore thumbs. But honestly: the rest of a 50-results per page is not much better. I counted **two** questions where it was used appropriately, in a sentence such as "can this be **solved** by ...".

Comment: I know. But I don't think I would survive wading through that much raw sewage.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29618731/5240004) is so beautiful it brings a tear to my eye. Found with a SEDE [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/382956/posts-with-solved-tags)

Comment: @theB: *oh-no-he-didn't* ... Did OP actually copy the entire given solution in the answer into his own question there?

Comment: It looks like he did, it's now been edited out. And sorry, but I couldn't stop myself cleaning that up. [Here's a screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyx4Z.jpg) that shows the cancerous title growth before the edit.

Comment: @theB: I amended [your SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/382958/posts-with-solved-tags) to include "solved', "fixed", and "answered" as those three seem to be the most occurring. It appears that "fixed" needs some more fixing as "fixed width" is actually something something CSS.

Comment: Good call. I added your changes into the other query. I also added 'updated' to the list, and added a space in the fixed prefix clause to try to filter the 'fixed-width' false positives. There's still a couple false positives in the list. examples [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192579) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27478810) I'll see if I can tweak it a bit more in the morning. (And SEDE updates tonight, so it'll be fresh data)

Comment: @theB: I don't hate "updated" as intensely as the others; possibly for these, it can simply be removed from the title. The other title edits may need more extensive editing inside the post itself.

Comment: Well, I did my bit, nearly 30 of those posts handled.

Comment: I think other than saying [solved] is not allowed in titles, you can also remind the user that if he already knows the answer, post it!

Comment: @Deduplicator: done about a dozen myself now, but it's certainly tricky. If you're lucky, it's just a single rollback, but some need more browsing through the entire history. ... Do we really need to go over all >3,000 Most Pressing Cases manually, as was done [back in '13](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172501/community-edit-request-solved-fixed-answered) when there were "currently 423 questions with "Solved" in the title"?

Comment: The '13 post actually refers to exactly this suggestion [as long ago as 2011](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86278), so it's a Meta-duplicate after all. It was not implemented then, so I'd *really* like to re-open this request for an automatic warning.

Comment: Do you like "S0LVED" better?

Comment: @tmyklebu: As long as it's just a warning, with fallback of alerting people (through smokey, a review-queue or whatever), we probably won't get s0lved. The problem is nobody kept on top of this madness.

Comment: Filtered a couple hundred more potential false positives out by skipping Qs with unmodified titles. [Query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/383146/questions-where-solved-was-added-to-the-title)

Comment: @theB: ah that is incredibly useful! Currently 2492 left. I suppose this may leave a couple of <5 min. edits but then again, that should not happen very often. Let's make a dent in this list first and see what's left after that.

Comment: The most recent few on that list have already been edited. I'm trying to pace myself on edits, so I don't spam the front page with a hundred old questions.

Comment: @theB: yes, I took care of a few really old ones but then realized this as well and so I switched to 'newest first'. Unfortunately, bumping up cannot be prevented! Guess we're stuck with this until somewhere after Christmas. Awaiting an answer to my original question, can you put your SEDE in an answer so it's easier to maintain, coordinate, and update? Similar to [This tag should not be legal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal).

Comment: [Dark background bug](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpy5f.png)

Comment: @TinyGiant: :P I actually made that in SVG but since we cannot upload those as images, it's merely a lousy gif. (Also I could not get the animation for the eye blinks right, which in itself was enough reason not to submit it.)

Comment: You can upload SVGs to [gist](http://gist.github.com), to include them just use https://rawgit.com/ to get a url with the correct headers.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I guess I'm getting old – can't get it to work! Maybe it needs a Github account. Does anything appear for you on this? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/350c2b7c07a37ea0a61b

Comment: I've edited it into your question, unfortunately it seems to only blink once (was that intentional?) [This is what it looks like for me now](http://i.stack.imgur.com/E9TWj.png)

Comment: @TinyGiant: Thanks for inserting - and, well .. no the eye blinks were to be continuous, except that they don't. I just cannot get the animation to repeat. Still, not bad for my very first SVG - it was just for a bit of a laff, and will probably be lost to a large portion of SO's younger audience anyway.

Comment: Ahhh, but to those who get it? Magical.

Comment: But if the user doesn't put SOLVED!!11!!!!!one!!!!!!! everywhere in the post, how will I know if they got their answer yet?

Comment: I'd add to this feature request that we could have a set of expressions for the title and the body that trigger a warning but do not prevent the question from being posted. My bugbears are "urgent" and "ASAP", but of course they can be used in circumstances that are not demanding special attention.

Comment: Welp, I clicked because I thought the [post was actually updated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/309266/7)! <_<

Comment: *Clippy, er, Stacky?* Now I am having flashbacks of prancing puppy dogs and dancing paper clips that refuse to go away .. ;-)

Answer (score 51):

This cute kitten<sup>1</sup> needs your halp!

[image: Help me, said the tiny kitten!]

To help in finding posts that need some love from editors, I've created a SEDE [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/383146/questions-where-solved-was-added-to-the-title), which Deduplicator reworked, to find questions that currently have solved, fixed, answered, and updated notes in the title, and have been edited. The query currently (1 Nov 2015) comes back with 2492 rows, all in need of some attention.

There's also the search [`is:q body:solved`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+body%3Asolved) that can be used to help find questions that will need more detailed work. This will be a much slower process. Currently there are > 65k questions in that search.

In both of the above there are some false positives, and certainly there are false negatives floating around that we aren't going to see.

Some coordination notes:

- If you have less than 2k reputation, and want to help out, that's fine, as long as you make constructive and **complete** edits to the question. In other words, don't just remove 'solved' from the title. Also, don't spam the edit review queue with suggested edits. There's enough work to do already.
- Closed questions should probably not be edited, to keep from wasting review time in the re-open queue.
- If the question contains the solution to the problem, use your best judgement in removing it.  **Old/abandoned questions that are worth keeping should have the answer pulled out and made into a community wiki answer.**
- If you have close votes, and the question should be closed, vote to close the question, rather than editing, so the roomba can do its job.
- If you have delete votes, well, you know what to do with them.
- Try to limit the number of edits you make at any one time. We don't really need to spam the front page with hundreds of edits.

---

**UPDATE:::::::::** (;-))

This morning when working through my daily share, I was pleasantly surprised to see a handful that had already been fixed!

[image: You're awesome!]
*(You know who you are)*

Statistics will be updated after the next SEDE update on November 8th.

---

Here's the actual SQL for the query that's linked above. <del>I welcome any suggestions. *(I am, dare I say, a SQL n0Ob)*</del> Thanks to Deduplicator for proposing the better query, and Rene for suggesting the `collate` improvement.

```sql
-- Reworked by Deduplicator
-- Use of `collate` suggested by Rene

with candidates as (
  select postid, max(id) historyid
  from posthistory
  where posthistorytypeid = 4
  group by postid
)
select p.tags, p.id [Post Link], p.lastactivitydate [Last Active], h.Comment
from candidates
join posts p on p.id = postid
join posthistory h on h.id = historyid
where upper(Title) like '%[\[(<]SOLVED[\])>]%' escape '\'
or Title like 'SOLVED%-%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
or Title like '%[\[(<]FIXED[\])>]%' escape '\' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
or Title like 'FIXED %-%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
or Title like '%[\[(<]ANSWERED[\])>]%' escape '\' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
or Title like 'ANSWERED%-%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
or Title like '%[\[(<]UPDATED[\])>]%' escape '\' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
or Title LIKE 'UPDATED%-%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
order by lastactivitydate desc
```

---

*<sup>1</sup> The kitten is a public domain image taken from [here](http://www.pdpics.com/photo/3535-very-cute-kitten/). Why include a kitten? It got you to read this footnote. And let's get real, no one is going to read a wall of text without some incentive.*

*The Kitty in the update is from [here](http://data.whicdn.com/images/125720816/large.jpg) found via Google image search.*

Comment: Instead of upper(title) do `where Title like '%[\[(<]SOLVED[\])>]%' escape '\' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI`

Comment: All posts that include pictures of cats get automatic upvotes

Comment: +1 for adding a footnote to the kitten picture.

Comment: @Rene - Added to the query.

Comment: I personally wouldn't go hunting for these things to edit. Should you run across them in your normal daily use, then make sure you are editing everything to improve the post.  But actively hunting down thousands of _trivial edits_ is not the most constructive use of time especially when there are far bigger issues to focus on.

Comment: @bluefeet, there are always bigger issues, regardless of what's actively being worked on. Though, I kinda agree with you, cuz *[solved]* in some titles doesn't really cause much damage.

Comment: @bluefeet - I know that there are bigger issues, but, frankly, how many of those are actually solvable problems? Is the CVQ ever, realistically going to be empty? (If 10% of the 31,000 people that could review close votes actually did, the queue would be empty in 2 days.) It's too easy to see the problems and become fatalistic about actually having an impact. I for one think that it would be a morale boost to be able to say, that a problem, even a trivial one, is resolved. Esprit de corps is a perfectly valid reason to do something, even if it isn't 'the most constructive use of time'. (1/3)

Comment: And maybe, just maybe, if we can get some people motivated to participate in a 'trivial' project, we'll get more participation in the things that have a larger scope. Further, having a specific focused effort on something that can actually be completed, helps fight the creeping apathy that is all too common around here. Will there be posts edited that really need more attention than they are given? Yes. Will there be things that should be deleted/closed that are edited? Of course. Will the site as a whole be better when this is done, even if it is only a little bit? I think so. (2/3)

Comment: Finally, very many of these posts will never be found naturally. Here's a [graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/382966/solved-scratch-query#graph) with the same data as the query in the answer above, that shows last modified date vs views. The vast majority of these questions are hiding in the dark and will never be found naturally by the people with the ability to improve them. Does that mean that we shouldn't even bother? (3/3)

Comment: Sure, it helps to fix them, but they aren't really causing a big problem, why make such a big effort to fix it? I don't like this whole... *"I made a difference!"* thought process. If you want to do something that makes a difference, work toward getting more of our existing users using upvotes and downvotes correctly. Sure, it's harder to measure how "successful" your actions are, but it's toward a goal that actually does make a difference. Edit them as you find them while answering.

Comment: The quickest, most direct, and likely most helpful thing you can do for this site is to write a good answer to a good question. Then, if you see these things in the title as you're working toward that goal, fix it!

Comment: Maybe add `solution` to your query?  I don't think it would pick up on http://stackoverflow.com/q/20661275/5111146

Comment: @bluefeet: there is such a thing as the Broken Windows Theory – which at least for me is not a mere *theory* (look: I spotted [a fresh one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33509193/2564301) while I was typing this!). As long as there *are* questions to be found with "SOLVED" in the title, people will assume it is the proper thing to do. Which it is not: "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions".

Comment: Queue on about 1932. I'm done with these so I'll start helping out from now on...

Comment: After a few days of work, I've removed a few thousands SOLVED/RESOLVED/FIXED/ANSWERED/UPDATED. I left approximately 50 as of July 22 2018.

Comment: @Cœur ...and now they're none. I went through all of them - there mustn't be others the next time SEDE will be updated (except those where the solved will be added this week, one locked post and one no MCVE one).

Comment: @double-beep good job! But it's a continuous job here: I remember I paused that task around 1st of January 2019, so the number of edits you've made for the posts of 2019 may give you a reasonable rate of occurrence of the issue (unless Shog9 added some blocker on it recently).