# How to respond to a large number of inconsequential edits

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I noticed a <2K user doing mass edits to remove "solved", or similar things, from the titles of questions. The problems I have with this are that

1. They're bumping old content for very little gain
2. It's adding a lot of reviews to be done
3. They ignore everything else which might be wrong with the question

I rejected and edited a few of these, (the ones which ignored a lot of other problems with the post), but I wanted to double check that this was the correct response. For a sense of scale, as of now they've done 46 of these edits in the past 20 minutes.

So, when I see a **lot** of suggested edits that are technically making the post better, but aren't doing very much/enough, what is the correct response?

1. Reject and Edit to make the necessary corrections
2. Improve the Edit to make any additional corrections
3. Flag for moderator attention
4. Drink until I stop caring

I know from reading other posts that looking for things like this to correct isn't encouraged, but I'd like a general rule to follow for how to handle it when I review someone doing this anyway.

Comment: As I mentioned [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309266/updated-actively-prevent-this-in-title-not-solved-yet#comment266137_309296) I'd prefer the focus to be elsewhere. There is no need to be hunting for these things to edit.

Comment: Either 1 and 4, or 2 and 4, or 3 and 4. *Pours drink.* What was the question?

Comment: I've ran into those too and just left a comment to the editor to check this question.

Comment: #1 Definitely #1. Especially since the post bluefeet commented on says, _"1. If you have less than 2k reputation, and want to help out, that's fine, as long as you make constructive and **complete** edits to the question. In other words, don't just remove 'solved' from the title. Also, don't spam the edit review queue with suggested edits. There's enough work to do already."_

Comment: Similar: *[only](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24592824/revisions)* [replacing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21567171/revisions) [intializing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14429532/revisions) [with](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13701772/revisions) [initializing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15770661/revisions) [...](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15847078/revisions)

Comment: Since they are looking for "solved", it is probably related to [Actively prevent this in title {NOT SOLVED YET}](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309266/updated-actively-prevent-this-in-title-not-solved-yet).  Unfortunately it seems to happen every so often - a relatively new user finds a meta post about removing something so start actively hunting to help "fix" the "problem"

Comment: So the issue is that they are improving the site, just not enough for you. So match their initiative and improve their edits or stop worrying about what they are doing.

Comment: @GEOCHET I feel like you didn't actually read my question.