# Solving the (RE)SOLVED title edit issue

Tags: discussion

Hey this is bugging the crap out of me. It is worse than tags in the title, editing them with `(RE)SOLVED` like this is some crappy phpBB forum!

I know [1442 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/442503) is not that big of a deal to probably add code to restrict people from editing titles to tag them this way, so who wants to help clean them up?

```
SELECT p.Id as [Post Link], p.Title, p.CreationDate
FROM Posts p
WHERE p.Title LIKE '%SOLVED%'
ORDER BY p.CreationDate DESC
```

*I did not know about the existing question about this, I guess this is just a call to arms to help drown out this ongoing problem.*

Comment: If you're going to do this SEDE will get out of date quickly, http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3a%22solved%22%20closed%3a0 would be better (`title:"solved" closed:0`). Also, on the ID column from SEDE alias it and you can get a link to the question, `p.id as [Post Link]`

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309266/1743880

Comment: @Ben - thanks for the tips

Comment: @JarrodRoberson *Now since we found a dupe for this you might want to edit your title and add SOLVED to it :P*

Comment: @Rizier123 - you know that is very very very tempting, especially on meta! :-)

Comment: I've dealt with a thousand of those, and as of today, you query is returning 185 rows.