# Should we do something about "sqllite" misspelling?

Tags: discussion, clean-up, typographical-error, spelling

I'm starting this discussion regarding a specific word. Note that I'm well aware that some other typos are more frequent than this one, but I'd like to narrow the discussion to "*sqllite*" because it's a product name.

It came to my attention that the **correct** spelling is with only one letter *l*:

> **SQLite**

Sources: [wikipedia.org](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite), [sqlite.org](https://www.sqlite.org/about.html)

Yet, even in Question **titles**, it's quite frequent to see it misspelled with a double *l*:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Asqllite shows about 700 questions with a misspelled **title** using "*sqllite*"

Remember that question **titles** are displayed in the "**Linked**" and "**Related**" lists, so the visible impact may be large.

I'd like to ask the opinion of the community regarding actions to take about it. For instance, should something be done about it or not?

Comment: Please elaborate your opinion. What are the consequences of the current situation? I myself am a friend of correctly spelled words but at the same time not the shining hero of the matter...  A question or answer is not really better or worse because of a typo. So the only real consequence to be worried about is whether a good question is findable. Anybody with a little experience or maybe after studying help pages, will search for the sqlite tag with a few freetext keywords.

Comment: @Yunnosch many question may not have the [sqlite] tag: maybe that could be a way to narrow the efforts.

Comment: If you encounter it misspelt, and you can fix it, do so. As we do with everything else, right?

Comment: @yivi my question is to know if community desires something to be done on a large scale (~700 questions here), as it can hardly be done by someone alone. Sure, I [did this kind of effort in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309266/actively-prevent-not-solved-yet-in-title/309296#comment612644_309296), but I'm not ready to do it alone again, as I'm afraid it may be a [Sisyphean](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sisyphean) task. I believe that it's best to ask if a community effort should be done about it. Or if it should be abandoned or done as a script.

Comment: Generally most misspellings are treated the same: as @yivi said, fix it whenever you encounter it, and on top of that, don't make so many edits as to flood the home page with spelling corrections. What makes this different to any other misspelling?

Comment: @BoltClock please post it as an answer: if it has votes, then it will be clear we should abandon cleaning efforts and let the database decay.

Comment: There are moderators who are in favor of using automated bots. I can't remember who, or what channel they meet in, but this would be a pretty easy target for it.

Comment: @BoltClock My question in regards to this, however, is SO's policy on trivial edits.. I'm (relatively) new as far as being actually *active* on this website, however, whenever I read a post, I'm always tempted to fix a couple of typos/formatting when I see them.. However, I'm always greeted with the "Avoid trivial edits" warning on the screen so half the time, I don't bother. Would this be considered trivial?

Comment: something along the lines of `update posts set body = REPLACE(body,'sqllite','SQLite') where body like '%sqllite%';` should be a quick and easy fix without causing bumps to the home page

Comment: I think this is pretty normal, for ex: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascrit

Comment: It's worth noting that the typo is [synonymized](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/synonyms) with the correctly spelled tag. So the tag should be *very* helpful in searching for questions about SQLite, even if the author had the wrong spelling.

Answer (score 26):

I do not believe the alternatives are *"mass edit or let the database decay"*, as you state in a comment.

I'm pretty sure you can find many other misspellings that are as prevalent or even more. We edit and improve those collaborately.

The more attention an individual post has, the more likely is going to be fixed by a passer-by. The less attention it receives, the more likely it's not that a useful post to begin with.

Personally, I do not believe this case warrants a coordinated effort, or to ask a SO staffer to do a DB search-replace. Even if we fixed all of them (and we did it correctly, and only where it mattered), more of those would still come in every day.

Maybe you want a more permanent solution? A filter so users can't post SQLite misspelt? We do not do spell checking in posts, but kind of offload that responsibility in the throngs off well-meaning users who like to correct things.

So in this case as in others like it, I believe the correct approach is the usual: found it in your way, it is **wrong** and you can fix it? **Fix it**.

<sup><sub>I edited 4 or 5 after reading your post. I couldn't help myself.</sub></sup>

Comment: Yep. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=postgressql .

Comment: @Gimby Apparently people building SQL related products have trouble creating names that aren't prone to be misspelt. :P

Comment: Indeed. MySQL VS MSSQL is another common confusion :)

Comment: As an Android user, I also often saw typo such as Andriod and Andorid...

Comment: @Gimby even google isn't able to differentiate (I keep seeing mssql questions when I'm typing mysql).

Comment: @yivi It's even worse for the procedural extensions - I always struggle to get *PL/pgSQL* correct.

Comment: Re *"... can find many other misspellings"*: Yes, [1808 and counting](http://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_2018-02-13.html)... There are 57 for Raspberry Pi alone (though some are for expansion).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I have built a similar list (but not including capitalizations or abbreviations) over time. Maybe I should look at Edit Overflow and see if I can contribute.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I can't find the source code of your program, and I'm on macOS...

Answer (score 12):

This probably isn't as big a problem as it looks. I don't think we need a huge edit hunt, but you should fix this when you see it (especially for brand new posts, since bumping them doesn't matter).

Here's why. There's no confusion about what you're talking about (unlike when people "misspell" *Java* as *Javascript*). Most search engines will find posts even when they have the misspelling:

> [image]

And searching for the wrong spelling on Google [gives you results for the right spelling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICElq.png) by default.

It doesn't matter if the asker uses the tag [sqllite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqllite), since it's a synonym of the proper spelling (which also helps with discoverability).

The real problem here is Stack Overflow's search engine (this includes the one used in the duplicate dialogue) cannot handle common misspellings like this. A search for `sqlite` should return results that include both properly spelled and misspelled instances. Thus, my solution isn't for you, it's for the developers:

### Fix the search!

Comment: errr.. 'sqlite' *is* the correct spelling, your answer reads as though it is the incorrect spelling

Comment: @harmic I'm not sure where you're getting that idea from. I know the correct spelling, but my point is that searching for the correct spelling (sqlite) or the incorrect spelling (sqllite) or some similar other incorrect spelling should bring up the same results (which would include results with the word both correctly spelled and incorrectly spelled).

Comment: But the screenshot with a *correct* spelling seems only to be demonstrating the part "With the correct spelling, I get correct results", which is likely not to be a surprise at all.

Comment: @Pac0 I think I understand what you're saying so hopefully the edits clear things up and address your point.

Comment: There is a kind of famous quote from Charles Babbage that I am rather fond of: *"On two occasions I have been asked, 'Pray, Mr. Babbage, if you put into the machine wrong figures, will the right answers come out?' I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question."*; the funny thing is, that with Google you will input the "wrong figures" and still ... get the right answers.

Answer (score 6):

I personally favor the mass edit in titles, preferably with a backend script that doesn't trip edited by, because the title search is too dumb to correct for misspellings. Since the edit is trivial, only the mass edit scripts can prevent bumps, etc.

Answer (score 5):

As the OP clarified in comments, they're well aware of this many typos.

My opinion: Only when the typos are significantly defacing the question, ***and*** fixing them will greatly improve the quality of the question, one should make an exit solely to fix them.

Otherwise, one should only edit to fix other greater problems like non-formatted code, and fix these typos *in addition*.

---

<s>I insist to post this only link as an answer, despite being link-only.</s>

[What are the best ways to find answers that should be flagged or edited? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83144/350567)

OK guys here's a brief summary of what the link contains:

> dinamically (4,800)
>   choosen (4,800)
>   fa(c|e)boo?k (500)
>   cant (190k), doest (1,500), aint (1,700), wont (94k)
>   jqu?(ee?)r?y (110)
>   javscript (2,800)
>   sqllite (4,700)
>   goggle (1,351)
>   teh (7,700+)
>   proble (1,258) and problam (257)
>   datbase (1,100+)
>   recieve (29k)
>   acheive (24k)
>   definately (3,285)
>   wierd (5,700+)
>   framwork (2,500+) and libray (1,252)
>   fi?re?fox? (378) and c((hr|rh)|r)ome? (2,027)

If you think SQLLite is causing trouble, then the same is for Good Morning, JavScript, Goggle, Datbase, Framwork, jQery, hey guys ......

Comment: Thank you for this link! As I commented to Peter Mortensen (author of Edit Overflow), I have built a huge list myself, and possibly more up-to-date than the referred one. As written on the first line of this present question: "_I'm well aware that some other typos are more frequent than this one_". And I've already fixed many many typo manually... possibly more than anyone else (except marc_s). I'm actually asking either for help or for clarification that there is no need to continue editing, and that I should leave those alone.

Comment: @Cœur Thanks for the clarification. I'll update this answer shortly.

Comment: Man, look at Datbase.

Comment: That's defiantely a loooooooot of mistakes. and this is only typos for single words and not things like "java script".