# Why do minor edits cause a post to be bumped?

Tags: discussion, edits

This has been asked at least twice before:

[Minor edits to old questions should not cause them to show up in "interesting" list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354119/minor-edits-to-old-questions-should-not-cause-them-to-show-up-in-interesting-l)

[Should VERY MINOR edits, NOT be bumped to the top?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267623/should-very-minor-edits-not-be-bumped-to-the-top)

One was down-voted out of sight, and the other had no satisfactory answer.
So, I think the time is right to ask this again, and hopefully get some better responses.

---

There has recently been a lively discussion about a ban triggered by approving a minor edit.

[I approved an edit adding backticks and fixing a typo - was that so bad as to deserve a review ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379754/i-approved-an-edit-adding-backticks-and-fixing-a-typo-was-that-so-bad-as-to-de)

It is currently the case that minor edits should be declined because the value they provide is outweighed by the cost of having them bumped to the front page.

> it is the responsibility of editors and reviewers to make a note of how old a post is.
>
> -- Yvette Colomb

This is widely known, and accepted, and is (as far as I'm aware) undisputedly the case right now.

However, it seems to me that bumping the post isn't actually a required part of the editing process.
It can be a useful thing to do to an edited post, if it will benefit from getting "another chance" at the front page.
But removing the bumping wouldn't prevent edits, nor would it impact their quality in a direct way.

> If the problem is that the edit will cause the post to get bumped, then isn't a "better" solution to make a way to approve edits without bumping the post? i.e. It shouldn't be "don't approve minor edits" but rather "don't bump minor edits"?
>
> -- AndyJ

That way we get the same bumping behaviour as now i.e. irrelevant edits aren't bumped.
But we also get the value that minor edits bring.

Others seem to share this point of view as well.

> if SO is a knowledge repository, does the age of a post really matter though, if it's still useful? Isn't it more important to maintain all the hard work people put in over the years than it is to clutter the front page for a couple of seconds? (Though I'd rather posts not get bumped automatically at all for edits in most cases, I'd rather err on the side of "let's fix content" than "let's not distract answerers for a couple seconds")
>
> -- jrh

Is there maybe a technical issue here that isn't visible from the outside?

Comment: There are numerous problems with this, which were brought up in the duplicates.  You haven't addressed any of them.  If you want to revisit a topic, you should be explaining why the problem brought up in previous proposals are either no longer applicable, or how you've altered the proposal to address them.

Comment: @Servy Hi, I'm having trouble finding the problems you say are listed in the duplicates. Could you provide some sources? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354119/310988 - No problems presented.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267623/310988 - The most upvoted answer says bumping isn't a problem and minor edits should be allowed, and should bump. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262813/310988 - If bumping is for the purpose of reviewing, then why isn't it a review queue rather than bumping? As far as I can see there were no "official" comments in any of them.

Comment: Read through the numerous comments, rather than only reading the answers.  They discuss numerous problems at length.

Comment: @Servy Sorry, I must be having an off day. I've been through the comments and couldn't see much. So I went through again and compiled a small list: Hans Passant "The point you probably ought to make is that a minor edit doesn't need to bump the question on the front page of every SO user that favorited the tag. A handful of views ought to be enough". John Dvorak "the bumps are not an issue on SO.". BoltClock "wow what a load of crap", that's not a reason, that's someone being an arse.

Comment: @Servy If there's an instance of this question with good quality information then it makes lots of sense to close this as a duplicate. But all I'm finding right now is hints and inferences that this is a cultural problem, with no concrete examples of the actual problems being solved. I'm trying here :/ and I'm obviously failing in your eyes ... can you give me a bit of help?

Comment: Did you really not notice the first comment posted, (and also the most highly voted comment on the whole page)?

Comment: @AndyJ It seems unfair at best to quote an obsolete revision of a post.

Comment: @Servy I'm sorry, I feel like we're looking at two totally different things here. Which post is "the" post? I've gone through the 3 I linked, and the post which prompted this post gathering the first comment on each question and none of them are the highest. One agrees with the change, one is irrelevant, one is about abuse caused by not using bumping as a review queue, and one is agreeing they would have approved the review that caused the ban.

Comment: @AndyJ So given your choices, of agreeing with the change, being irrelevant, pointing out a severe vulnerability to abuse, which the existing feature exists specifically to address, and also being the highest voted comment on the entire page, and one advocating making a minor edit, you couldn't figure out which of those comments might be pointing out a problem you should have addressed in your proposal?

Comment: @Servy Oh, did you mean "answer" rather than "comment"? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262815/310988 If so then what you're saying is starting to make a bit more sense to me. That answer wasn't overly clear though, it implies the front page is being used as a review queue, but isn't that what the review queues are for? Where's the reasoning behind that?

Comment: @TylerH Fair point. But I was trying to show that rather than "this is how things work, and these are the reasons why" we get "idiot. do what I say because I say.". It feels like there are a group of users which have this knowledge, and all the other users that don't have this knowledge. And the group of users with the knowledge simultaneously get angry having to field questions about it, and refuse to document it. I have a Q on a Q&A site, I've put a lot of time in to researching it so far, I'm trying here, but I don't have this knowledge, and I don't think it's unfair to ask for it.

Comment: @AndyJ That answer is making the same argument as the comment I was referring to.  Edits are only reviewed when the editor has less than 2k rep and is not the owner of the post, and the suggested edit review also has a long history of being terrible at its job and constantly approving bad edits, so no, the review queues *don't* solve the problem of bad edits being made.

Comment: @Servy Thank you for sticking with me, even if I was being annoying/frustrating, I appreciate it.

Comment: FWIW the "users want to review recently edited posts" on the front page point is new to me too. I guess some eyes on edited posts are better than none, though I have to point out that the pages that needed editing already got through that test. Yet another scaling problem with SO's content moderation; darn. Maybe there's no great solution for stuff like this when a site gets big enough to the point where abuse can happen on a large scale. I wonder how Wikipedia manages this?

Comment: Also... I think I'm done suggesting edits for a while, this is just too complicated for me to deal with, it was bad enough when I could get in trouble for "too major" with some reviewers ("Oh no! Too much red and green!!" even though intent didn't change) but now that I guess "too minor" has been sort of reinstated as a reject reason, with the reasoning behind it being "don't bump the post", it pretty clearly seems to me now that reviewers don't think suggested edits are worth the effort, and I'm starting to agree: It's not worth my effort either. Disappointing. I liked that SE feature.

Comment: Also I'm not going to gamble with non minor edits because at this point I think there's a high chance that somebody with no domain experience will fail to hit "skip" and reject a valid edit.

Answer (score 5):

After some back and forth with Servy, who very kindly stuck with my incessant questions, I now have a better understanding of the chain of logic here.

The root problem is that edits can be used as a form of vandalism that is low-effort for the perpetrator and have a low visibility to the rest of the users.

This kind of problem would normally be addressed by using a review queue, but historically review queues have had a very bad detection rate when applied to posts with small changes. In this situation there is a proven record of bad edits being approved due to complacency/whatever on the part of the reviewers. (Unfortunate, but understandable.)

So, there's an initial period when a users edits are reviewed, and hopefully during this period they fall in to the habit of creating substantial edits which produce less load and less false negatives. Then after that period edit posts are bumped so that if a bad edit does slip through it can potentially and hopefully be picked up by users hitting the front page.

BoltClock discusses [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262815/310988) the first part (bumps are used as a review queue), but only alludes to the second part (review queues don't work as well as bumping, even if bumping has drawbacks).

> The reason editing posts bumps them to the front page is to give other readers an opportunity to review the posts that were edited, as well as the edits, in context, especially if the edits are substantial.

Comment: In principle, I agree, but [every user does not need to read every bump](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379831/9209546). This can easily be limited so each user sees only, say, 20% of bumps. Which still ensures every bumped post gets exposure, just not exposure to the whole world.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, no bump is shown to *all* users, @jpp. The homepage adapts to your tag preferences and observed browsing history, showing you a sampling of active questions in your areas of interest. You probably see about 90 questions on the homepage - that's about 14 minutes worth of new questions OR new answers OR edit-bumped questions/answers. But your homepage shows a lot more than just 14 minutes, and a lot less than everything in the time it does show.

Comment: @Shog9, Hmm, I know this is anecdotal but I've frequently seen a user edit a minimum of 5 posts and all of them pop up alongside each other (provided they do it before a new question is posted). Maybe, as you say, this is due to my "observed browsing history" or my preferences (whether or not they are the default ones).

Comment: Nearly every question on *my* homepage right now is tagged either [javascript] or [c++], @jpp. If someone edits a bunch of [javascript] questions, I'm probably gonna see 'em on the page, at least most of them, at least briefly. OTOH, you probably won't. The oldest modification on *my* homepage right now is 3 hours old... But I certainly don't see *all* modifications made in my tags for the past three hours. And neither of us will see every edit made in our preferred tags for three hours or even 30 minutes.

Comment: @Shog9, Yes, I agree of course I will only see python-tagged posts because that's the tag I watch, that's exactly what you're saying here: "If someone edits a bunch of [javascript] questions, I'm probably gonna see 'em on the page, at least most of them, at least briefly." In my opinion, that "most of them" would be better at 15-20%.

Comment: That just raises the question: who sees which 15%? The only sensible way is to make it random, which we do! But, it's a bit more complex than that, @jpp - 10% are just random, recently-active questions filtered by tags & score; the rest are ranked by stuff like age, score, views & relevance. So *initially*, those edited questions get a huge bump (both in the random 10% and the ranked remainder) - but that falls off pretty quickly, and not uniformly - so you might see everything for a couple minutes, but stuff starts to drop off right away and this increases the further out you get.

Comment: @jpp Hi, I don't know if the 5 posts popping up alongside each other that you noticed were edited by me, but note that as an active editor I roughly try to limit my consecutive edits to max 15 posts from the same tag, which also makes it hard from fixing frequent typos in popular tags as raised in [Should we do something about “sqllite” misspelling?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375665/should-we-do-something-about-sqllite-misspelling). I don't use any queuing tool, so sometimes I may involuntarily bump many [tag:android] from just fixing `listner` → `listener` for instance.

Comment: @Cœur, No, my settings are set so I only see [python] questions. But this kind of activity, *mostly* otherwise harmless [and, where not, easily caught], happens in all popular tags.