# RSS feed with only new questions

Tags: support, rss

I have a bunch of RSS feeds for various SO tags. However, lately they have become much less useful, since various people have taken it upon themselves to edit years-old questions in meaningless ways (example: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17484354/revisions).

This makes it show up in my RSS feed.
How can I exclude these "changes"; and get only new questions?

Example feed: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/stl

Comment: I understand your question comes from a place of irritation.  However, it might be more productive to state: "I would like to be able to sort tag RSS feeds by creation date rather than by LastActivityDate.  For instance, visiting https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/stl/newest would show only the newest posts for the [stl] tag."  It may persuade people to support your feature request more.

Comment: I really do want to see "new posts", as opposed to "new and updated posts". (BTW, I would be happy with two feeds - one for new posts, one for new and updated ones)

Comment: I'm glad people are doing edits to old content, I find a lot of messy old posts that nobody's coming back to. If this content's going to be here for all of eternity it may as well present the topic as cleanly as possible.

Comment: @jrh yes but there is a difference between making a meaningful edit and doing an edit which just slightly alters the way a block of text is rendered, but does not make it any more readable. I often have a *really!?* reaction to edits done on MSO where a question with a thick layer of dust on it gets hoisted back into the active questions because someone just *had* to fix the way Stack Overflow was written...

Comment: @Gimby IMO, the solution is to make a UI where you can opt out of seeing edited posts in the same place as new ones; "minor enough to warrant bumping" is a flawed review concept, [especially for suggested edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380516/how-much-does-correctness-matter-in-so-answers/380523#comment673034_380523) because there's no agreement on what "too minor" is (officially that's *not a reject reason*), and reviewers are intimidated by "major" edits (rightfully so because they aren't expected to have domain knowledge). End result is, this site is wasting its potential.

Comment: Ideally the suggested edits queue should be the "peer review" and edited questions wouldn't show up there at all, but I am guessing that the community no longer really trusts that system and some users want to do more reviewing and see recent edits "Active Questions", and some don't; I am aware that it is important to see recent edits for the sake of re-opening "fixed" questions, too. However I don't think any of this is a reason to limit editors; I really think this is another case of SO outgrowing its review tools and a good UX / design would make everyone happy here.

Comment: Also... one thing reviewers might have overlooked, proper use of code markup (as in, backticks or four space codeblocks) [gives hints to Google Translate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blkrJ.png). I know how pointless those "add backticks only" edits might seem, but the reality is, if a class name like `Control` got translated to something else, C# is written in English, and it might make things harder for people who are trying to find information.

Comment: Now that I'm using "newest", I'm less concerned about this, but today's example is https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8207049/revisions, where someone took a question from 2011, and decided that "it's" was intolerable and had to be fixed :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is already possible: add `&sort=newest` filter on the URL

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=stl&sort=newest

Also, when you choose the filter to ["Newest" on the questions list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl?tab=Newest), Stack Exchange will provide the relevant RSS feed on the right sidebar, below Hot Network Questions.

> [image]

Answer (score 12):

This is already possible:

Go to https://stackexchange.com/.

Create a filter.

Use the RSS feed for that filter.

An example for such a feed is https://stackexchange.com/feeds/tagsets/363789?Sort=newest. Do note I recommend creating your own.