# How old is too old to edit a question?

Tags: discussion, edits, old-questions

I have a question involving editing old questions that belong to other users.

Is there any age where a question should be left as is and not edited at all? Excavator badge does require editing a 6 month old post, but how old is too old? On other forum-like sites, there is a term called "gravedigging", a frowned-upon practice of commenting/editing/replying to an old post. So, is there such a policy on Stack Overflow where we should not edit an old post? And, if we do, would the edit reviewers accept it regardless, or would it get declined?

Comment: It is all dependent on the quality of the edit.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Okay. So, would things like minor grammar edits be inappropriate on an old question?

Comment: Possibly yes, edits can be rejected for that reason because minor grammar edits introduce no major improvement, whilst formatting code is a big improvement and is almost always approved

Comment: Before 2K rep you suggestion edit must be review. And Edit bump the question giving it more visibility. As suggested in [Edit] help page(https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) : _"**Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged** - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe."_

Comment: *"gravedigging", a frowned-upon practice* - We're a more sinister sort of community and embrace such macabre practices. We even reward you for acts of [necromancy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer).

Comment: @MarkAmery You deserve so much rep for what you did there

Answer (score 80, accepted):

There's no such thing as too old to be improved. If you can make *substantial* improvements to a post, then by all means, edit it. We're working together to build a high quality Q&A library; we want things to be improved, no matter how old they are.

However, if you're only making one very minor improvement (as in converting one line of code from inline code formatting to code block formatting), you usually should not edit the post. While we do want to keep things as relevant and useful as possible... if the problem is so small it will barely affect anything at all, then it doesn't need to be improved.

Comment: High quality libraries do not include typos.

Comment: I believe this answer is only relevant for users with rep lower than 2000 since they need to have their edit approved by someone else.

Comment: @svgrafov- I think not. Below 2000 you have to have your edits approved. But the point you should be learning is what sort of edits are appropriate. You should have internalised that by the point that you're allowed unrestricted edits, not change your behaviour now that someone's not checking your work.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever But surely the only reason minor improvements are inappropriate is that they cost more of a reviewer's time than they are worth. If the only person whose time you're 'wasting' is your own, and you're willing to spend it, doesn't a minor improvement become appropriate? (assuming it actually is an improvement)

Comment: i don't see why typos, even minor ones, should go unfixed? if you feel like fixing it, go ahead i'd say.

Comment: I think a better example would be something like editing an inline snippet of code to include backticks. That's not really necessary unless there are other things you can fix.

Comment: I feel like this needs more thinking. Really, why not just say : if you are over 2000, feel free to correct any OBVIOUS grammar, spelling, or syntax errors since nobody is going to waste time reviewing your edit. If you are below though, just stick to reel necessary improvements. @Damien_The_Unbeliever I know it sound like changing behavior... but isn't it for the best ?

Comment: Maybe minor edits should be allowed for < 2k users, but without the +2 rep bonus

Comment: Note that [some meta posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381138/4975230) are against "bumping" the post for the sake of disrupting the front page workflow, though I'm with @Braiam ; if nobody fixes this stuff it'll be here forever... any 2k+ volunteers want a list of random little fixes? I'll start making one if anyone's interested.

Comment: There's not just [one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1287/excavator) but [two](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1286/archaeologist) badges for editing inactive posts, so I think it's safe to say this is encouraged behavior.

Comment: On a *high-traffic* site like Stack Overflow bumping is not an issue ***at all*** and can never be an argument for not editing a post. It is a myth. On lower-traffic sites you should voluntarily rate limit yourself to, say, one per day.

Comment: The "too minor" rejection reason was removed a few years ago, because it prevented those small improvements. That means **S.O. developers want you to do even small improvements**.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer fair enough, but what do you propose? Is somebody from staff going to post a "deal with it" response to people saying they don't want their front page cluttered? Are mods going to start banning all reviewers who reject "too minor" edits? From my experience there's robo-rejectors ("I am frightened by red and green"), robo-accepters ("I'm just here for the badges"), major edits only ("Don't clutter my front page!"), minor edits only ("I don't care to validate technical content"), and people who are knowledgeable about the subject and can review properly. What can we do?

Comment: @jrh As you noticed there is no chance to get everyone on the same page. I'm just commenting because the second paragraph in this answer is not correct.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer yeah I don't have any ideas on how to fix it either; it might be a slim chance but I'm hoping that if I keep poking people one day I'll get an idea...

Answer (score 7):

I've made essentially the same point before on [Super User Meta](https://meta.superuser.com/a/10816/31641), but this version is more detailed.

If you don't yet have the rep to edit, your edits must be approved by two other users to go through, so you're using their time. Bear that in mind, and don't waste their time on trivial things. Many people are stricter about what what counts as "trivial" on older posts (I'm not, myself, but it's unlikely to be me reviewing your edit suggestion).

As a suggestion here,

- fix things *as you come across them in your normal use of the site* (don't go out of your way to look for problems);
- fix things *that others will agree need fixing* (so skip most small typos, especially on older posts, because *many people* don't care about them, even if you and I do).

Once you gain the rep to edit directly, you're taking up no one else's time, and if you want to fiddle with minor typos that's up to you (I do, because typos annoy me). However, be aware that edits surface posts to the top.

Again, some suggestions,

- on smaller sites, don't do a bunch of edits at once and bump all the new posts off the front page (this doesn't really apply to Stack Overflow, unless you're focusing all your edits within a single tag);
- look over the entire post when editing, including title and tags, and tidy the lot;
- if you edit a question, consider glancing over its answers as well, so the questions and the answers are surfaced only once (this is especially useful if question edits (say RFC 2606 domain names) require matching edits in answers).

Comment: There's also a difference between an inconsequential typo ("to" used instead of "too") and a consequential typo (`=` used instead of `==`).  I think it's OK to fix minor consequential typos.

Comment: My judgement would be that if it's consequential it's not minor, even if it's only a few characters.

Answer (score -16):

As far as I know, the age of a question doesn't matter when you're editing it; what matters is your reputation on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "what matters is your reputation"? I expect that's where most of the downvotes are coming from.