# Suggested edit was rejected, but the rejecting user applied almost the same edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22380894), and another user rejected it and did the same edit by himself,

Well, not exactly the same: I did replace all lowercase "I"s to uppercase since it's [the correct way](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/33116) of writing the first-person pronoun, and he left them the same way they were.

Comment: I can't see a reason why he would reject and edit, specially as he made no significant imrovement IMO.

Comment: Looks like that was a few weeks before that user became a moderator (last election [ended March 19th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381524/2019-community-moderator-election-results)). Not that that changes anything.

Comment: You could ping them directly on that question and ask them about it.

Comment: Rejecting your edit didn't make any sense, especially when considering that Jean only removed 10 chars (noise) but left the grammatical errors (not just the `i`'s) unattended - hmm..

Comment: Likely a misclick or an error. I wouldn't dwell too much on this.

Comment: @yivi He might lost his keys like Tim.. ;) And then edited the question himself..

Comment: And as others mentioned, Jean-François wasn't even elected when he reviewed that particular suggested edit.

Comment: Perhaps he didn't want to be [banned from review for approving such edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379754/i-approved-an-edit-adding-backticks-and-fixing-a-typo-was-that-so-bad-as-to-de) :)

Comment: It could be as simple as just pressing the wrong button.

Comment: I routinely reject edits that do not improve the readability of the question as long as any reasonable reader will have no problem grasping the underlying issue.  It includes capitalizing `i`s, adding apostrophes to `dont`, and such.

Comment: @PM77-1: Please stop voting on those edits, at least. Fixing punctuation is improving readability.

Answer (score -43, accepted):

Sorry but changing `i` to `I` isn't substantial enough to warrant an approval and +2 rep. Do that when you have enough reputation to edit without approval.

<s>So I just rejected, but removed the useless "Thank you" that you didn't remove. I think I would have approved if you did</s>.

But my memory fails me after all this time, so it appears that you removed the "thank you" as well, my bad. So, I rejected it because I probably didn't think it was substantial enough. I can't provide you any other explanation. This is still a minor edit.

the community seems to think I did a mistake. I honestly don't remember this particular edit. I probably made a mistake then, and posting on meta was the right thing to do. Next time when you see something that you don't agree with, it would be better not to wait too much before reporting it.

I remember some consensus somewhere where you should not accept minor edits, but rather reject them and apply them yourself. Seems that this consensus exists only in my imagination. Duly noted.

Comment: Please check the suggested edit, I did remove "Thank you" as well

Comment: Fixing grammatical errors is another way to helping the community, The editor itself returns an error when I don't change enough, I think reviewer checks if the suggested edit is right or not, not checking the quantity of edit is substantial enough or not

Comment: I think you erred on this one. The [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22380894) both fixed the pronouns capitalizations and removed the useless "Thank you". It lef some of the noise at the end of the question, but so did your edit for that matter. This seems a valid suggested edit, IMO (unless the question is too bad and should be closed, but that doesn't seem to be the case).

Comment: Forgive me, but it seems as though you are implying that rep gain is a factor in the rejection. If rep gain should not be a factor in editing, then surely it should not be a factor in rejection.

Comment: @DarkSuniuM Fixing grammatical errors *can* help the community.  But while some are extremely helpful and greatly improve the ability of readers to understand the post, some don't meaningfully change how well people understand the post.  That there's a system imposed 6 character limit doesn't mean every change that's more than 6 characters is a meaningful improvement to the post, and an edit *not* being a meaningful improvement to the post *is* a valid rejection reason for reviewers.

Comment: @Servy It doesn't explain rejecting and editing the post with less improvement by another user, So basically you're saying changing "in my program i have a variable named i and i want to add it with 5" to "in my program I have a variable named `i` and I want to add it with 5" is not a valuable improvement for someone who has lower rep than u, but if you don't do it and only delete a "Thank you" note at the end, it is valuable ? ( I did delete the "Thank you" note as well )

Comment: @DarkSuniuM I don't necessarily agree, but the justification is that low rep user edits require approval, and therefore the time of at least three reviewers. Low rep users making trivial edits incur an significant overhead in reviewing time but high rep users can make trivial edits without using anyone's time but their own.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic It explains more, but it still doesn't explain doing the same edit with less improvement by same user

Comment: Capitalization on MSE from 2010 covering even smaller edits than this one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53451/332043 . The edit in question did, as already mentioned, remove noise and actually improve the post. The edit should've been approved.

Comment: @DarkSuniuM I think not making the same capitalization fix was also a mistake, not something Jean did on purpose.

Comment: "This is still a minor edit." But then you made an even more minor edit...

Comment: This answer flies in the face of Shog guidance: Get rid of the "too minor" reject reason entirely. If it's really too minor, reviewers should demonstrate that by providing a not-minor edit. If the reviewer opts to build upon the edit instead of starting over from the current revision, **then it isn't too minor!** https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039

Comment: Re your edit: Your edit was still more minor than the original edit. Why would you reject an edit that actually does something constructive and edit with parts of that edit *because you felt it was too minor* when yours wasn't really much better? When it goes as far as it does, you could improve the edit rather than rejecting it, because it does still go towards improvement

Comment: Come on Jean, just admit you made a mistake. It is not the end of the world. These things happen.

Comment: I appreciate the time you spend to moderate the community, I even myself voted for you and I won't revoke my vote even if I could, In Avg 1/15 of all my suggested edits are getting rejected, the only reason that made me create this meta post was the "Reject and Edit" with the same changes that I did, Thanks for your honestly and the courage to admit it

Comment: I really had this consensus in mind when replying, hoping that someone would dig it up, but since noone does, well, so be it. The inverse problem of people approving any edit is an issue bigger than rejection from time to time, the proof that people are human and not roboreviewing. -24 accepted wow :) at least you agree with the answer

Comment: Why would one reject an edit for insignificance and then apply a (nearly) identical edit themselves?

Comment: cs95 answer provides the links I was looking for: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302300/should-we-approve-suggested-edits-that-just-remove-thanks

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I'm a little confused, who is saying that gaining rep should not be a factor in editing?

Comment: @Alex: Do you gain rep when you edit a post?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Yes, if the edit is accepted you have less than 2K rep.

Comment: @Alex: I realize that, of course. My question was "Do YOU gain rep when you edit a post?"

Comment: @MarkBenningfield No, since I'm >2K. But I don't understand the argument, for <2K's rep gain is clearly a factor in editing and OP is <2K?

Comment: @Alex: I suggest that we continue this in chat, if you like, or that you post a Meta question asking why rep should not be a factor in editing, perhaps with a link to this discussion.

Comment: This Q/A pair is case in point why I don't bother suggesting edits anymore, we didn't get through all of [reviewer bingo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381411/how-old-is-too-old-to-edit-a-question/381413#comment679653_381413) though; it's all down to luck whether an editor's strategy matches the reviewer's strategy. Otherwise, like major edits? Get rejected by somebody who doesn't like to read. Like minor edits? Get rejected by somebody who wants major changes only. The current system isn't working.

Answer (score 36):

Your edit should have been approved.

It's true, this was not a substantial edit, but that doesn't mean the edit was not good. Lack of substance in an edit would matter if there were other issues with the post *besides* the one(s) you addressed. In this case, I can't see any.

Insubstantial edits would also become grounds for rejection if you see a pattern of abuse from a particular user. Going through [your reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5616565/darksunium?tab=activity&sort=revisions), that thankfully doesn't seem to be the case.

The consensus at [Removing someone else's "Thank you!"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267384/removing-someone-elses-thank-you) and [Should we approve suggested edits that just remove thanks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302300/should-we-approve-suggested-edits-that-just-remove-thanks) also seem to indicate as such.

Answer (score -19):

It can well be missclick or an error. Happened to me too already. The easiest way to rectify a false rejection of a suggested edit is to apply the edit yourself. It means that somebody is deprived of a bit of rep but it is not really a big deal as long as it doesn't become a pattern.

Regarding the Is: maybe an oversight while hastening to rectify a previous error.

Comment: If you click "reject and edit", the rejection isn't actually done. The reject and edit is pushed at the same time, and regular reject requires a reason. Reject and edit can be canceled. You can't misclick to reject edits, the system isn't designed to allow that. Mistakes do happen, yes, but a misclick is an extreme stretch...

Comment: @Zoe I didn't mean "reject and edit" but just "reject" and edit later. I just checked and this option exists.

Comment: Regular reject requires a reason, editing later shows "reject", not "reject and edit". The edit in question explicitly shows "reject and edit", which means it was done from review

Comment: @Zoe "which means it was done from review ", not really. If you are in a post and someone suggested an edit, you can reject and edit it right there, you don't have to go to review for that

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that is still considered a review. If you do that, you do get a +1 on the review counter for suggested edits, and it handles the review. Any action you take is identical to going to the review queue and stumbling over that question. If you bypass the edit to conflict it, that shows "conflicted with a subsequent edit" and not "rejected"

Comment: @Zoe Yeah, I'm aware of that, but "from review" sounded like you were in a review queue

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto good point - it's still a form of review task though. I'd clarify my comment if there wasn't a 5 minute edit window ^^"