# Understanding what's valuable to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, clean-up

Possibly like most users here, I visit Stack Overflow almost daily because it's an absolutely amazing resource. While I've been using the site for maybe a decade, I only started actively participating on the site around eight months ago as certain global events having left me with a bunch of extra time on my hands.

Initially I started out by answering questions, and I still do that a fair amount, but a few months ago I discovered the existence of coordinated efforts to clean up the site. In particular, I discovered [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/) (SO Close Vote Reviewers), a chat room dedicated to this goal. The experience has been great, and I've learned a lot, and my current views on how cleanup should take place have been heavily influenced by the active members in that chat room.

---

My desire to help with this cleanup effort led me to post the question *[Can we speak out against all the pronunciations?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402796)* in order to solicit feedback on what would be the right approach to dealing with the questions mentioned there.

There were a lot of views and upvotes on the question, which indicated to me that there is interest in tackling this issue. There were also two answers posted, one voicing vehement agreement that such posts should be removed, and one advocating restraint so that posts with value are not deleted along with all the others.

So far, so good. Things got considerably more interesting when I posted [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402815/8372853) containing a curated list of posts that I felt were actionable. This answer was met with quite a lot of resistance, with users pointing out that they felt many of the posts had value, and one user even helpfully compiling a list containing a subset of these posts that they wanted to preserve. In terms of action on the list in my answer, all but one of the posts have been closed, most have been deleted, and three have had historical locks placed on them.

My takeaway from that post was that while users had feelings about deleting these posts, no one was actually disputing their off-topic nature. I felt like the primary objection was that they would have preferred that the list had never been published in the first place, or in other words, that we should let sleeping dogs lie.

---

Spurred on by what I considered to be at least a moderate success, I then posted the question *[Please stop having opinions about things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402905)* where I provided a list of closed questions that I felt were all uncontroversially off-topic, and almost exclusively worthy of deletion, and asked users to help me with deleting them. This post was met with a *lot* of resistance, at least as indicated by the voting activity.

The objections that were raised included, as before, that some of the posts have value. More prominently, there seemed to be several users who felt that inviting users to take actions on these posts actively detracts from other efforts at site wide cleanup, in particular the efforts to curate more recent posts. Again, in terms of actions, the community seems to be clear; 48 out of the 56 posts have already been deleted within 24 hours. Of course, there hasn't been enough time for users to cast undelete votes, and there may be flags on some of the posts for historical locking, so it's premature to conclusively say what the results of that post are.

On the other hand, there has been sufficient time for actions to have been taken on the pronunciations post, and so far, exactly one post, namely *[What is the official pronunciation for "SQLite"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655034)* has been undeleted, and is now one vote away from being reopened. I have promised in both of my posts, that if any particular question had contentious activity, I would flag it for historical locking. However, as mentioned in *[What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587)* a good rule of thumb is:

> Does this question teach me anything that could make me better at my job? Can I learn something from it?

And my answer to that is, absolutely not. As a result, I cannot bring myself to flag the post, and for that I do apologize. So just to get this out of the way, does this post have value enough to be kept around? If so, I am grossly misunderstanding what is considered valuable on Stack Overflow, and the next section is moot.

---

Now for my main point, which is, I would like to get feedback from the community on whether posts like the ones mentioned in this question are a good idea. I have other searches of this nature, and other lists of posts that I would like to ask the community to act upon. In particular, curating these lists is also something I would like to get community support on, although this has the issue mentioned above of running the risk of valuable posts being deleted as well. Given the response to my previous posts, I'm certainly not comfortable publishing those lists without a clearer understanding of the community consensus, if there even is one. Before I try anything like that again, here are at least some of the points I would like clarity on:

1. Does the community think it a good idea to keep around low value posts, several of which admittedly do have sentimental value for many of us?
2. Does the community think that publishing lists soliciting user actions is a good idea? Are there certain criteria that should be applied to these lists, such as restricting them to only posts needing closure, or only posts needing deletion? Is time a factor, i.e. should the lists be restricted to posts that are less than five years old, or less than two years old? There are likely other criteria that have not occurred to me.
3. For those who agree that such posts are a good idea, and I know there are at least a few, I would like feedback on how I can frame these posts to be more palatable. I would like to avoid having users feel like I'm ignoring their views, or that I am going on a blind deletion spree. To be fair, a spree is not entirely inappropriate, but I am taking care for it not to be blind. I would welcome any suggestions at all on how to frame such calls for action, since I have clearly not done as good a job of that as I might have.

---

Finally, I would like to sincerely apologize to any users who were offended by my publishing those lists, and there certainly seem to be several of y'all. I honestly didn't think there would be any controversy surrounding this issue, and I would have made a post like this one first if I had had any inkling of that.

Also, if you personally had a post that you liked that got deleted as a result of my previous posts, I'm sorry about that as well. If it's any consolation, and it probably isn't unless you have the privilege of viewing deleted posts, there are links to all of them in my previous posts.

Comment: "I would like to avoid having users feel like I'm ignoring their views, or that I am going on a blind deletion spree" and yet, you've here reposted the *one* single post that got un-deleted with a clear message that you think it has no value because it doesn't fit your view of "Does this question teach me anything that could make me better at my job? Can I learn something from it?" From where I'm sitting it almost looks like you want it go get deleted again.

Comment: @Scratte There's no almost about it. I won't vote on that post again, but I absolutely think it has no value, and should be deleted. Just for clarity, are you saying the answer "pronounce SQLite however you want" is useful to you?

Comment: I absolutely think it has value. All the arguments you guys have been having about how pronunciation questions have no value strike me as utterly absurd. Communication is very important. If other people cannot understand what you're saying, then you are going to have a hard time communicating with them. I've largely stayed out of it because it's difficult, as a moderator, to express an opinion without it being interpreted as an official judgment, but honestly this crusade is going too far in my opinion. That that developer has a rather flippant attitude doesn't make the question off-topic.

Comment: I read it after it's un-deletion. I had no idea that the were two different ways and I also had no idea that the official way was different from mine, so yes, I learned something, that I found useful for my job, since now I may make less of a fool of myself. I guess I'll wait with the rest of them for 2034 or whenever I get to 10K.. unless your meta posts get deleted before then, which is a real possibility, since it's very popular to delete things..

Comment: @CodyGray Wow. So that question is on-topic? Given that you voted to reopen, and haven't put a historical lock on it, I take it you think that the question deserves answers? And just so I'm clear on this, if that question were asked today, you're saying it's on-topic and shouldn't be closed?

Comment: Yes. Yes. Yes. No doubt whatsoever in my mind. The only reason it would be off-topic would be if it were opinion-based, but it's not soliciting opinions. It has an objective answer. Why should it need to be closed?

Comment: @CodyGray Very interesting. I'm looking at the list of pronunciation questions as I write this. At a glance, at least half the questions could have "official" added to the title. So by your logic, if one does that, that would make them on-topic? Or am I misunderstanding what you think the objective part of the SQLite question is?

Comment: "How do you personally do x, please share your opinion?" is entirely different from "What is the correct way to do x?" I think this is self-evident, and not simply based on the inclusion or omission of a particular keyword.

Comment: @CodyGray That's fair, the "official" keyword doesn't have anything to do with it per se. I think I understand where you stand at least on the pronunciation topic though, and it seems you think a decent chunk of the questions in that list are on-topic. I must say, that sounds like a very slippery slope. Almost any post could be framed, with just a little effort, into one seeking an objective response.

Comment: It's not a slippery slope. The criteria is, is it a practical problem related to programming, and can it be reasonably answered in our format. I don't see these questions running afoul of either of those expectations. And I can imagine plenty of hypothetical questions that would. For example, if it's about a hypothetical language/tool, or one that doesn't exist, then it's not a practical problem. If it's not related to programming, then it's off-topic. If it's taking a poll, then it's too open-ended, and thus off-topic. I really don't see the problem.

Comment: I'm going to ignore your latest edit to the title, and use the old one, i.e. "How do you pronounce SQLite?" (Not that I think your edit improves matters). Do you actually think that's a *practical problem related to programming*? If so, it appears we do programming *very* differently.

Comment: If you aren't talking about the code you write with other programmers, then you're doing it wrong. Communication about programming is a very practical concern.

Comment: Valuable to whom? There are several Stack Overflows. There's the one that provides answers to thorny problems and edge cases encountered by experts, those striving to be experts, and those who are about to learn way, **way** more than they wanted to. There's the one that explains how to do common things that trip many people up, like why you never loop on EOF. There's the stack Overflow that's helping folks out with their homework. There's the Stack Overflow discussing the canonicity of ancient religions and modern fables. It's a wide, wide world.

Comment: @CodyGray I do talk about code with other programmers, some of whom barely speak English, and pronunciations of terms has never really been a hindrance. If getting the pronunciation of SQLite, or any specific term actually affects how you communicate with other programmers, then I would venture to say that you're doing it wrong.

Comment: You haven't experienced suffering until you've sat in on a fight over taxonomy. Politics. Religion. SQLite. Software repository layout. All are peanuts compared to taxonomy wars.

Comment: @user4581301 That's basically my question. In my opinion, all those groups are trying to solve programming problems, and SO should preserve what's valuable in that regard. Expect for the last one, they should try their luck on reddit ;)

Comment: True enough. I branched out too far and netted in some Stack Exchange on the last one.

Comment: I applaud your efforts @cigien but honestly I think it’s a step too far and will do more harm than good.

Comment: @Lankymart Yes, that's certainly possible. Would you care to expand on why you think so, preferably in an answer? It would be really helpful information to figure out a strategy that shifts that balance in the right direction.

Comment: I'm surprised that people consider "how to pronounce" questions on-topic for SO. It strikes me as a language problem, not a coding problem. Obviously being able to communicate is important for software development, but that doesn't make it a programming question. By that rationale, questions asking "how do you spell..." would be on-topic as well.

Comment: @CodyGray Personally, I don't think that pronunciation questions hold value that should be preserved on Stack Overflow. And when it comes to official pronunciation, ask Delphi developers how to pronounce Delphi and we'll go to holly war... and European developers don't use official pronunciation but Greek one. So sticking to official has zero value... everyone uses the one they like.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar While I take your point about there being disagreement, I don't think that is a very compelling argument against these questions. Surely there are plenty of other issues that Delphi developers get into holy wars about, most of them strictly technical. C programmers certainly have their share. Mention brace styles in a crowded chat room, and prepare to see the pitchforks come out. Which is why questions like, "Which is the best brace style?", are clearly off-topic. But, at the same time, "Which brace style is used in K&R C?" is not off-topic.

Comment: "I honestly didn't think there would be any controversy..." Ok. Unfortunately with a big enough group there is a high chance for at least a small controversy. Safest would be to always assume controversy and discuss the matter before publishing hit lists. :)

Comment: @CodyGray I agree about brace styles... but how do you ask about pronunciation when you cannot even ask for official one without getting opinions. I agree that we should not destroy valuable posts, but we either need to broaden the scope then or we should be able to cleanup unsuitable posts. From experience, new users don't care if some post is closed or has historical lock, they will still use it as a template when asking their own questions. It is damned if you do damned if you don't kind of situation.

Comment: Any effort that reduces the number of useless search engine results one has to wade through to find the good stuff is appreciated, personally.

Comment: FWIW, I've said "integer" differently from everyone, for over 2 decades, mostly because I worked with myself or other self-taught programmers. I am working something a little more corporate now, with the college grads, and I have been laughed at for it a few times after they "corrected" me. I still stay it the way I've always said it, my code is just as good (or better :p) than the people who say it "right", so IDK. They know what I mean when I say it my way, the purpose of language is thus fulfilled.

Comment: Can't we like, google for how to pronounce these words and hit the little play button to make the voice say it?  And then if we don't like how its said, yell at google instead of stack overflow?

Comment: @Taplar Not really. It takes people that use them to know how. Try Google with LaTeX.

Comment: I don't like deletions much. The content in the listed questions wasn't outright harmful, just merely not a good fit and maybe sometimes even a good fit. Closing should have been the natural reaction. It seems SOCVR is more like SODVR. I'm worried that the targeted approach kind of includes an inherent bias and may destroy too much valuable content in its course as collateral damage. Especially if there is no clear consensus like in the pronunciation case.

Comment: Here I'm in agreement with @Trilarion . Once a question is deleted it's unlikely that the folks who could counteract and restore an in-dispute question will even know it happened.

Comment: How do you pronounce "gif"? 

Answer (score 94):

The golden rule here is, quite simply, that **we don't want to destroy value**. If the post adds any value whatsoever to the community, the site, or even the larger Internet, then it should not be deleted. That includes concerns as simple as breaking links to popular Q&A by deleting them.

If a particular question is no longer a good fit for our site, and we don't want to keep accepting answers, but has *already* received answers that provide a positive contribution, then we will close it and/or apply a historical lock. But deletion is generally inappropriate and unwelcome.

As are campaigns that go dig up old questions to delete. There are plenty of *new* incoming questions that are in need of moderation/curation. Those questions have not yet been answered, and will be seen by far more eyeballs, so they are in much more urgent need of attention.

**I strongly recommend against going and hunting for old questions to delete.** That is a waste of everyone's time. The primary motivation to delete questions is when they are causing a problem. If these old questions are attracting answers, showing up in review queues, or whatever, then they are, by definition, creating a problem and should be handled. But if they're just sitting there, then there's really no point in going and digging them up just to have something to flag. I want to [quote Brad Larson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290371) here:

> What I do care about is preserving something that others have found to be valuable. Votes tend to indicate this, although not always.
>
> [You have to consider] what flags are a good use of our time. If a short answer that happens to contain a link has been significantly upvoted, it's been shown to have value to others. I personally hate to delete things that others have found of value, since I feel that isn't making the Internet a better place.
>
> There's plenty of steaming trash coming in every day. What George was saying is that maybe we shouldn't be bickering over old, highly voted content and should instead focus on downvoted garbage coming in right now.

Although he may no longer be a moderator, I still follow [George Stocker's mantra](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286970):

> We do not delete good content. We do not delete good content.

If there's some specific, old question that you really think is causing harm, then, sure, bring it up on Meta, in SOCVR, and/or in a moderator flag. But don't just go looking for stuff to waste time on. And don't do keyword searches that are filled with false positives.

Comment: I'm backing this "fight" to stop to delete old, often highly up voted and visited content for being off-topic nowadays, maybe 6-8 years later. we have "close" and "lock" and "historical lock" to stop further interacting with those. Users might continue finding those Q/A's useful. 

Close and delete the new crap !

Comment: @Vickel Why though? By your logic, if we let the new crap hang around for a bit, several of them will likely get views, upvotes, and eventually, in 5-10 years, lots of users might find them useful as well.

Comment: @cigien as an example : the link you mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655034/what-is-the-official-pronunciation-for-sqlite, just lock it or close it. done deal. At least it will help to avoid new questions for the same topic.... And as we talked yesterday, it seems to be a very big playing field. And I said: "Concentrate on the new Crap"

Comment: @Vickel The one that was un-deleted and reopened? The only survivor? Really?

Comment: @Scratte the only one I could see (<10k), and yes, It's off-topic, IMO and close it, but don't DELETE it

Comment: @Scratte And it's actually a bad example of what I'm standing for, as it is not a very old post, neither highly upvoted or visited

Comment: There are things that have value, then there are things that are valuable for Stack Overflow. These questions may pass the first hurdle, but I doubt it pass the later one.

Comment: @Vickel then you want no crap deleted :)

Comment: @Vickel I like it :) I guess we can't agree on everything. It's more useful than most of the other posts that I see.

Comment: @Braiam you know me by now, I CV daily :)

Comment: I still don't know what the problem is. Is this question attracting low-quality answers? Is it creating any sort of problem on the site? Why does it need to be removed, closed, or anything else?

Comment: So, how do you pronounce *controversy*? Is the emphasis on the second or third syllable? :-)

Comment: The first syllable, @AdrianMole.

Comment: @Vickel but that's not enough, you know? Sometimes we have to [delete "fun" questions too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73415/213575), and [popularity isn't everything](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/01/31/the-trouble-with-popularity/).

Comment: It's not subjective, it's not meant to be fun, there was nothing unconstructive about it (it wasn't leading to arguments or discussion), it wasn't soliciting opinions, it wasn't even a subjective question. Nor was it all that popular; it had only received one answer. None of the canned arguments apply here.

Comment: @Braiam yes, pure fun questions can go, sure

Comment: @CodyGray is the SQLite question linked in the OP one which you feel adds value to the site? If so, could you extend your answer to explain how (or point me to any relevant comments)? Because I fail to see the value of an official answer that boils down to "I do X but do whatever you like" for a term that has zero ambiguity to begin with (everybody who knows about sqlite will understand you regardless if you say sql-lite or sq-lite)...

Comment: It's incredible how many upvotes this answer has received, considering how it describes the polar opposite of actual practice.

Comment: @exnihilo Actual practice is to close and delete a huge number of Q&As, both old and new, that provide considerable value but don't fit narrow interpretations of the site's format.

Comment: @StackOverthrow Not sure what you're talking about. What I've described here *is* the "actual practice" and "official policy", both in terms of what the moderator team does and consistent with what I see others doing. We certainly do close huge numbers of Q&As that don't fit within the site's format, but nothing here argues against doing so.

Comment: Such a short memory @CodyGray has.  I spent several months on a number of answers that **had value** - and when you started an argument with me, ***your diamond*** gave you the power to delete every question I had written of value, and close my account.  It's ***cute*** that you have an **"official policy"** and an **"I'm angry"** policy.

Comment: Yeah, I honestly have no idea what you're talking about, @Y2020-09. There are, of course, other aspects to the official policy that I omitted mention of here. For example, plagiarism, duplicate answers, and so on are all deleted as a matter of policy. Looking at the history of your account, it seems that you may have had an issue with repeatedly posting identical answers to multiple questions, which is not allowed here.

Comment: @CodyGray And I'm not sure how you could be completely unaware of what's been going on around here for the last several years.

Comment: I couldn't agree more.  I have often found locked/closed content that was incredibly useful.  I have also found several "duplicate" questions that were more instructive than their non-duplicate counterparts.  The point being that not everyone agrees on what is good/useful, but if enough people have interacted with something it is a sign it is providing value to at least a subset of users and imho should be left alone.

Comment: I don't understand how deleting old content adds value in any way.  It would possibly make sense if SO had a problem with people being led to bad, old answers, but that has not been my experience at all and I use the site pretty extensively.  When deleting old posts, the chance you are deleting something that at least a subset of users find useful is very high, and the chance you are improving the experience for users seems to be incredibly low.  I also don't think  votes to re-open is a great metric for how useful old content is, as many users won't even realize it's gone.

Comment: @Cole Deleting old content doesn't *necessarily* add any value. However, deleting *harmful* or *low-quality* content does add value. The vast majority of these low-quality posts that we delete (I will delete tens to hundreds of them per day, and I'm only one moderator) have unbelievably low views, so virtually no one ever notices that they are gone. Removing the chaff improves the odds that people searching for an answer will find a good one. This is working behind the scenes for you, without you even realizing it. We don't really use votes to re-open as a metric.

Comment: The "logical" programmer in me says "delete them". They are off topic and they do have an impact, they promote asking similarly bad questions. If I see the question was answered, even if it is marked as closed/offtopic, that's still evidence I should just ask my off topic question anyway. The top answer on [tag:webgl] is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966779/learning-webgl-and-three-js). I'm sure many people found it useful. Being closed it's rotting with invalid links. IMO It should be deleted. There are lots of useful questions that are off topic. Being useful is irrelevant.

Comment: I can't really upvote this because I have to disagree on the hard line stance of "If the post adds any value whatsoever to the community, the site, or even the larger Internet, then it should not be deleted." It's my opinion that it's a net negative for everyone to keep a post that is 1% valuable but 99% dead links, dangerous / outdated information. In addition to the confusion it will also serve as a [dupe "anti-target"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63489497) which prevents anyone from posting a new, clearer question.

Comment: "There are plenty of new incoming questions that are in need of moderation/curation. Those questions have not yet been answered, and will be seen by far more eyeballs, so they are in much more urgent need of attention." I think this is misguided too, the old questions are more broad and will get more search hits, at this point after 12 years all new non-dupe questions should be very niche content, so I'd say the older questions are more important for Google searchers.

Comment: Also... I have to say I can't get behind the idea of "if a question has been around a while and has upvotes it's precious and should be kept", that stance is too reliant on popularity and essentially lets Google's search algorithm run this site rather than relying on curation (which is, I think letting the tail wag the dog, and misses the question of how many people would be here *without* curation and discredits what this site is all about). Instead, why not ask why a post is popular and learn from it and serve those visitors better?

Comment: With all that said in this specific case I'm against the idea of posting search results for "bad words" in posts on meta and forming a voting mob. I think the rule for deletion should be just "I know content that does more harm than good when I see it", in an ideal system edits would be able to rewrite or replace outdated or badly flawed posts but SE kind of half baked the idea of maintaining old content, so pragmatically deletion or heavy edits by high rep users is the only option left for a lot of posts where the author's never coming back.

Answer (score 18):

I have a feeling that I'm being misunderstood or that my words are being twisted, so thank you for asking this question so I can chime in to explain myself better.

Yes, [I have said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402909/266143):

> The time and effort spent on those 50-odd posts is better spent on helping users that are posting questions now.

The reason I said that, was because it looked like you were actively searching for random keywords that *might* indicate a problem with question quality, and I find *that* a counter-productive activity, given the outcome: within a day or two of you posting that pronunciation list, dozens of on-topic, interesting, well answered, well viewed, no-problem-causing questions got deleted by a handful of users.

Why? Apparently because there are two ways to pronounce Delphi.

So I wrote that as an answer to your second question, because I didn't want something like to happen again, and I didn't want it to set a precedent. We all know how those mass closures and deletions go: sloppy, barely overviewed by those not in the know (i.e. not on Meta for two days) and hardly ever reversed, [which I also explained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402905/please-stop-having-opinions-about-things/402909#comment808524_402909):

> I'm not going to go down into that psychological argument. In my experience, people are eager to close and delete stuff, but less so to undelete and reopen. It's like they feel like they're held more accountable for the latter. After all, once closed or deleted, very few people see those posts and challenge these actions.

Even though you were probably entirely right with that second question; I didn't find anything of value in the first dozen or so opinion-titled questions!

The point I was trying to make with that remark was that if you're bored, go grind a review queue or visit a chatroom to find questions to close. Don't use the search to find stuff to delete, and definitely don't rile up a Meta mob to aid in said deletion. That's all that I meant with that. I did not say that we should never delete old questions. We definitely should delete some questions, [namely](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions):

> Questions that are extremely off topic, or of very low quality

No matter their age. And I think, given the upvotes on my answers and comments, and [Cody's answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402945), that I am not alone in this.

And about the search engine argument, which I may or may not have called "utterly absurd", who knows, many comments were posted and deleted: a question like "How to pronounce SQLite" does not, what many people apparently believe, push, for example, the [first Google hit for "how to password protect an sqlite file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669905/sqlite-with-encryption-password-protection) off of the first page of search results. So in that sense, pronunciation questions are, apart from being on-topic, not problematic at all to have on the site. They don't come in the place of other information, like in a book that has to be printed on a limited number of pages.

Yes, search engines are having a problem with this site: it's because queries like [winforms numeric only input](https://www.google.com/search?q=winforms%20numeric%20only%20input%20site:stackoverflow.com) have 3850 hits, [asp.net core iformfile null](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+core+iformfile+null+site%3Astackoverflow.com) have 2890 and [git move last commit to another branch](https://www.google.com/search?q=git%20move%20last%20commit%20to%20another%20branch+site%3Astackoverflow.com) have 25.900 hits. But that's a whole nother problem, and not solved by removing a handful of questions that do not turn up for those queries.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the search engine argument. I got the impression that commenters got incredibly side-tracked on this issue. Yes, searchability *is* important, and it’s *problematic*, and should be improved. But mass-deleting old questions such as those mentioned in the other discussions doesn’t help. What helps is to prevent worthless duplicates accumulating in the first place, and instead closing them all in favour of one canonical answer.

Answer (score 12):

It appears that there is a significant and increasing resistance to curating old content from some parts of the community, predicated mainly on the influx of new questions. The argument from this section of users appears to be that curation effort is best focused on handling the deluge of new questions, especially since curating older content is often a very labour-intensive process. Further, they argue that old content that is highly upvoted should be left alone, because the high number of upvotes indicate that said content has been helpful to a large number of people.

(As context, I have been subject to this viewpoint in my recent efforts to get some old, large, tags burninated.)

For me, that argument doesn't hold any water, for the simple reason that **nobody has a right to dictate how a curator should decide to spend their time curating**. They are, after all, giving that time freely.

You're allowed to have an opinion on how valuable (or not) those efforts are, but expressing that opinion in a way that is discouraging or disparaging to that curator is not on (e.g. using the expression "utterly absurd").

Similarly, a belief that a certain curation effort is wasting Meta's time **should also be kept to yourself**. This site is supposed to be democratic - if you don't like a particular curation effort, downvote it, or just plain ignore it. Standard Be Nice protocol applies.

As for leaving old content alone, anyone who has ever worked in software - which, I would hope, would be *most* of Meta - should be aware of technical debt. Code and content don't "rot", but standards change, and refusing to curate old content based on new standards strikes me as unreasonable at best and irrational at worst.

I don't believe that the desire to leave old content alone comes from a place of user maliciousness, rather from Stack Exchange Inc's continuing failure to provide tools that allow this sort of curation: it is a symptom, not a cause. But those users espousing this viewpoint, for whatever reason, need to be aware that they are **actively discouraging** curation efforts, and in doing so likely driving curators away from this site - at a time when we need them most of all.

---

To answer the question as presented: your curation effort to identify low-value content is absolutely valuable, regardless of the impression you may have received from certain parts of the community.

I agree one thousand per cent with you that on a website ostensibly about programming, questions about pronunciation are irredeemably useless garbage that should be incinerated with the heat of a million suns. Anyone trying to argue that pronunciation is vital to communication has apparently never had a real conversation with other human beings. Human beings don't open a dictionary or Stack Overflow when they have different ways of pronouncing the same thing - they figure it out while they're having that conversation, either by settling on a pronunciation that everyone understands, or by each member having a mapping table in their head of "when X says Y, they mean the thing that I know as Z". This isn't something that requires rigorous negotiation, it just *happens*.

The problem is that the claim about these questions being "valuable" isn't actually about their value **in terms of programming**, it's about their value **for SEO to Stack Exchange Inc**. That's the whole reason "we" don't want to delete them outright, merely close them.

In short, don't suggest the deletion of old questions - suggest that they be locked (or just flag them yourself). That keeps everyone happy.

Comment: Thank you, finally I don't feel weird for completely ignoring how stuff is pronounced. As a non-native English speaker, I just pick whichever way sounds right to me and I hope that the other person understands. After all, other people use different pronunciations all the time and I can understand them. Asking how one pronounces things is just a waste of time for me.

Comment: **"Anyone trying to argue that pronunciation is vital to communication has apparently never had a real conversation with real human beings. Real human beings don't open a dictionary or Stack Overflow when they have different ways of pronouncing the same thing..."** <--- where is that [meta-tag:bounty] button?

Comment: Flagged for bigotry: I am a real human being, even though I prefer to consult reference materials to make sure I am pronouncing things correctly, in order to be understood and avoid looking like an idiot. It's just a special case of how I generally prefer to avoid talking nonsense.

Comment: @CodyGray I think flagging for bigotry is a bit extreme, the text doesn't really seem to imply that you, or anyone else is not a "real" human being if they choose to be pedantic about pronunciations. Anyway, I've edited the text while hopefully maintaining what I think is the answer's meaning. Is this acceptable to you?

Comment: The mention of flagging was a joke. Sorry for the confusion. Yes, mods can raise flags. Some of those flags (e.g., comment flags and rude/abusive flags) are immediately binding, causing the flagged post to immediately evaporate. In other cases, the flag will just end up on the moderator dashboard for another moderator to deal with. But no, I didn't actually flag this. I was just making a point. I wasn't in any way offended. The One True Scotsman fallacy isn't offensive; it's just wrong. And so is the claim that no one is interested in consulting reference materials.

Comment: @CodyGray Ah, no worries. I find sarcasm/irony/etc a little difficult to guage in text, especially with people I'm not used to communicating with via that medium. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I am also the sort of person who looks in a dictionary or wikipedia to see how things are pronounced. But I wouldn't post a question about it on SO, because it's not a programming question.

Comment: `refusing to curate old content based on new standards strikes me as unreasonable at best and irrational at worst` Allow me to completely disagree with this. Good answers to even *ancient* content do not lose their value because newer standards kicked in since. Anyone who ever had to read and/or maintain legacy code must have had head-scratching moments where something made no sense at all. A good answer to an *old* question on SO can often explain the whats and whys in those cases, in ways recent answers pandering to newer standards never could.

Comment: @dxiv I think you missed the point. We're discussing *deleting* old content, but updating it or editing it or posting a new Answer on it.

Answer (score 8):

Deleting questions that have absolutely no value on the site or are even actively causing harm is a good idea irrespective if it was posted a minute ago or 10 years ago.

The point of deleting is to prevent people from finding this information in the future.

Your post [Please stop having opinions about things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402905) unveiled a lot of questions that were in need of removal but no one had the guts to suggest it or no one bother to do anything about yet. I didn't check all of the links, but I agree that most of them were easy decisions to delete.

> Does the community think it a good idea to keep around low value posts, several of which admittedly do have sentimental value for many of us?

It's never a good idea to keep around anything that wouldn't help you become a better programmer. It's not about sentiment, it's about value. If answers to a question contain information you can't find anywhere else or explain them in a clear way and helpful way or if a question is a good signpost then there's probably no reason to delete it.

If all answers are either wrong, contain misleading information, or explain the same thing for a hundredth time in the same way as before then deleting the whole thread will not make the programming community any worse.

> Does the community think that publishing lists soliciting user actions is a good idea? Are there certain criteria that should be applied to these lists, such as restricting them to only posts needing closure, or only posts needing deletion? Is time a factor, i.e. should the lists be restricted to posts that are less than 5 years old, or less than 2 years old? There are likely other criteria that have not occurred to me.

This depends. We trust you to make the initial judgement. If you know the topic or can say with full certainty that the Q&A has no value then you can request our review. If you form a list of such questions it will help us go through them quicker.

The factors you should consider are number of views and number of upvotes on both question and answers. They are usually good indicators of how useful the post is.

Time is irrelevant, but do note that some very old questions are left purely for historical reasons. Judge each question on its merits. Just because it is off-topic now does not mean that it should be deleted now. Even answers pointing out typos are useful in certain situations.

It's also worth considering linked questions. They appear on the right of the question and show posts that are linking to the current one. If a lot of posts link to the question then a historical lock might be a better option than deletion.

> I would like feedback on how I can frame these posts to be more palatable

Definitely don't flood us with them. There's already plenty of posts that need deletion and not enough curators. We are drowning in an ever-increasing wave of new questions of which many need to be closed and deleted before they get a foothold.

If you want to post such lists then maybe it would be a good idea to post your justification for deletion together with a link. A number of views and upvotes would also be helpful.

---

Keep up the good clean up efforts. Focus on the worst of the worst first, and if you have time and willingness to find terrible posts then that's commendable. But, please make sure that you're not depriving us of helpful information.

Comment: _Deleting questions that have absolutely no value on the site or are even actively causing harm is a good idea irrespective if it was posted a minute ago or 10 years ago._ --> that gives me the impression that you agree with the deletion of old questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224703/discussion-between-dharman-and-10-rep).

Comment: *Even answers pointing out typos are useful in certain situations.* I'd like to note something here, not particularly for you Dharman but because I've seen some people get a little over zealous when it comes to typo questions. The close reason for typos specifically states "this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers," so typo-questions and their answers that do help future readers I think are exactly the type this answer is talking about there that are worth keeping.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my stance on this: while deleting old questions does contribute to the site, I feel there are more important things to curate (such as new questions).

Stack Overflow exists to be a repository of knowledge. So for this reason, any content doing harm, or giving misleading content should be deleted.

I feel that digging up really old questions and telling people to delete them in bulk has two downsides:

1. It's just not the best thing to spend meta's time on. Moderating new posts is ***much more*** important, as that's what everyone will be seeing. Unless a group of old questions is doing harm (such as providing misleading information), there's no need to delete them. It takes a lot of delete voters to delete popular questions.
2. When deleting such old questions in bulk, some questions have value, which may be overlooked and deleted. If there are 100 questions to be deleted, for instance, and one of the questions has like 10 upvotes, with a small amount of views, someone may overlook it, and it will get deleted with 3 delete votes. Actions in bulk overlook the decision required to analyze each question and see if it's useful.

#### However, this ***does not*** mean that if you see an old question that has no value, that you shouldn't delete vote it. By all means, delete vote on it, and post a [del-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/del-pls) request in SOCVR if you wish. Even if the question doesn't cause harm but has no value, go ahead.

But, don't do it in bulk and bring it to meta. Don't compose a list of 50 questions or so and delete vote them just because they have no value. That, IMO, is wrong and should be avoided.

Comment: "*Moderating new posts is much more important, as that's what everyone will be seeing.*", that is not true. This is what we see, but most users find SO pages from google search which gives them old questions.

Comment: "Even if the question doesn't cause harm, go ahead".. :(

Comment: @Scratte Oops, I did not mean that. Let me fix it now.

Comment: Unless a new question gets many views it is not a problem. The incoming rate is 8000 new questions per day (weekdays) and this will not change unless some barriers are put up. It is more important to concentrate on the questions with [the highest view rates](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/120907/highest-view-rate-questions-non-community-wiki-4) (globally or [in particular tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/164178/highest-view-rate-questions-in-a-particular-tag-non-community-wiki)).

Comment: @Dharman If a question doesn't have value to most people, someone landing on its page from a search engine is likely to be among those few people that the question _is_ of value to them. Why is that a problem? If, on the other hand, the question has absolutely no value whatsoever, then yes, it should be deleted. One should still decide if it's the best use of their time to go hunting for such questions that might get one view every couple of months or so though.

Comment: @41686d6564 this becomes a problem when values of different visitors clash. Then you need to choose whose values to prioritise higher. That SQLite pronunciation makes a good example. Some curious passers by may get happy finding the answer to this at Stack Overflow. But if you think about folks like me, these posts damage usefulness of SO for us. I go to SO to find answers about coding problems and when I need to find something about SQLite, I want to avoid having my search results polluted by pronunciation debates...

Comment: ...(in fact, not just polluted but dominated because such bikeshedding naturally gains popularity, views and upvotes pushing it higher in the search results compared to boring technical explanations of how things work)

Comment: @gnat Yes, the thing is we differ on what is useful for SO and what is not. Some people like having that answer, but others don't want to it to pollute SO.

Comment: What's with the bling on this post? Besides, "have no value" seems to be very opinionated. While some of us see value in the deleted posts, the Question author sees none, and wants the material gone for *everyone*.

Comment: @Scratte I have no idea what bling means, so I don't understand what your comment refers to.

Comment: I'm referring to the the big text in bold, that's not a headline, but using headline markdown to get more attention.

Comment: @Scratte I want to emphasise that. Previously my answer had a score of -1, now that people see that it has a positive score. I've seen other people do it on meta, and I am not doing it to get more attention. Regarding "have no value", I think people with the del vote privilege can judge whether or not a question has no value. (ofc, question has to have a negative score, but whatever). Since del votes don't age away, it doesn't matter if everyone disagrees with them.

Comment: No, Questions do not have to have a negative score to be deleted. Users with delete vote privileges are conflicted about whether these post have value. Also, are you implying that users without cannot judge their value? (For what it's worth, I usually downvote posts that has bling on them..)

Comment: @Scratte I am not implying anything by that sentence whatsoever. All I mean is that if you think a question has no value, then delete vote, no matter the age of the question. Also, while I cannot control your vote, it seems weird to do it in this case, as I am not doing it for attention, but instead I need to emphasise a _key_ point in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

1. Don't go [looking for trouble](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381552/209139), unless it's trouble you can deal with 100% on your own, without taking up anyone else's time.
2. Don't delete things without very good reason. Old questions are rarely causing problems, and may be valuable in some sense.
3. Some of the questions you're concerned with actually are on topic, or at least borderline, so the controversy was warranted.

You can bring more value to the site by editing poorly written but valid content to increase its value or by curating (and perhaps deleting) *new* questions and answers than you can by deleting old questions that no one's looking at anyway.

To put it another way: review queues exist for a reason. No need to make your own.

Comment: There is no delete review queue.

Comment: *"old questions that no one's looking at anyway."* What makes you think people are not looking at them?

Comment: "Old questions are rarely causing problem" - I disagree, old questions are one of the worst things here, especially when they don't have concrete answers! Every single false positive or comments-only bad question I have to wade through when researching a problem undermines the original point of this site.

Comment: @ChrisBaker I see more examples of bad questions among old questions rather than the new ones, the reason being is that we have stricter guidance now and new questions are closed and deleted more rigorously. Whenever we can, we should focus our efforts on old questions that are forgotten and need similar treatment as well

Comment: I have a question about your 1st point: By this "without taking up anyone else's time," do you mean avoiding big efforts like cleanups that would need other people to do because it's so long like the targeted cleanups mentioned in this post, or do you mean curation activities that necessarily take up other's time like when a suggested edit requires two reviewers to approve? One I would agree with, and the other not so much, so I wanted to see which way to interpret it :)

Comment: @DavyM. More the latter. By all means make suggested edits, but don't *go looking for edits to suggest*. When you don't have the power to make unilateral edits, do them only when you happen to notice them. If you *do* have the power, by all means go looking for them. The same applies to closures, etc. By all means do them from review queues or as you come across them as part of your normal browsing of the site, but don't search for them unless you have the power to deal with them unilaterally. (A group targetted cleanup like this one kind-of counts as an *ad hoc* review queue for my purposes.)

Comment: Ok good we're on the same page then, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @ChrisBaker and when you found the answer did you go back and answer them, and close others as duplicates? That is the correct solution, not deletion.