# "FIXED" or variants in question titles

Tags: discussion

This question is in referral to [Writing files in java, changing case and number *FIXED*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52828749/writing-files-in-java-changing-case-and-number-fixed?rq=1). What's the official policy on the `*FIXED*` in the title? Is it useless clutter that should be edited out? I think we should.

Comment: It provides no useful information. If there is an accepted answer, then it should be "fixed".

Comment: In this case specifically, there was an accepted answer.

Comment: It should be removed. Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172501/204841

Comment: @Mackycheese21 we can see there was an accepted answer before clicking on the question, if we see it from the question list. It doesn't add much. Anyway "accepted" only means "the OP said it worked for him", not "it's a good answer", necessarily. I wouldn't give too much credence to that check

Comment: FIXED/SOLVED and variations should be removed from the title, likely along with the answer edited into the question (rendering question "unclear" as it usually no longer ask for anything). The https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309266/actively-prevent-not-solved-yet-in-title (I used it as duplicate) provides detailed guidance on what type of editing should be done. (I rolled back that [invalid edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52828749/3) on the question in question :)).